# PHP replace string with ****@mail.com

Tags: php

how can convert ?

Is there a quick and easy way to replace every letter of a word with an ****@mail.com

For example

```
$mail = 'stack@mail.com';
echo $mail;
output -> s****@mail.com
```

Thanks for answer me.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: sorry my english is not good @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explode() and str_repeat()

```
$a = explode("@", $mail);
$mail = str_repeat("*", strlen($a[0]))."@".$a[1];
```

Comment: thank you very much it's working

Comment: can i show first letter in email ?